# Two-way WPF binding to Properties of a class inside of an ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, binding, wpfdatagrid

I've searched as best as I can, and I can't find an answer to this specific problem that I have... WPF binding seems to be great and all, but I end up banging my head against the wall more often than not.

Okay, I have a singleton class which is ultimately the one that I'm binding to:

```vb
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class AmandaSeyfried
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Shared _config As New config

    Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, E As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Protected Overridable Sub OnPropertyChanged(propertyName As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName))
    End Sub

    Private Shared _thisInstance As AmandaSeyfried

    Protected Sub New()
        ' initialization goes here
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function GetSingleton() As AmandaSeyfried
        ' initialize object if it hasn't already been done
        If _thisInstance Is Nothing Then
            _thisInstance = New AmandaSeyfried
        End If

        ' return the initialized instance
        Return _thisInstance
    End Function

    Public Class CountryTranslation
        Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

        Private Property _englishCountryName As String = ""
        Public Property EnglishCountryName As String
            Get
                Return _EnglishCountryName
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                If _englishCountryName <> value Then
                    _englishCountryName = value
                    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("EnglishCountryName"))
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        Private Property _foreignCountryName As String = ""
        Public Property ForeignCountryName As String
            Get
                Return _foreignCountryName
            End Get
            Set(value As String)
                If _foreignCountryName <> value Then
                    _foreignCountryName = value
                    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("ForeignCountryName"))
                End If
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    End Class

    Private WithEvents _countryTranslations As New ObservableCollection(Of CountryTranslation)
    Public Property CountryTranslations As ObservableCollection(Of CountryTranslation)
        Get
            If _config.GetKeyTextValue("countryTranslations") <> "" Then
                Dim reader As New IO.StringReader(_config.GetKeyTextValue("countryTranslations"))
                Dim Serializer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(_countryTranslations.GetType)
                _countryTranslations = Serializer.Deserialize(reader)
            End If

            Return _countryTranslations
        End Get
        Set(value As ObservableCollection(Of CountryTranslation))
            _countryTranslations = value
            RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("CountryTranslations"))
        End Set
    End Property

    Private Sub CountryTranslationCollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) Handles _countryTranslations.CollectionChanged
        Dim newStringWriter As New IO.StringWriter
        Dim NewSerializer As New Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(_countryTranslations.GetType)
        NewSerializer.Serialize(newStringWriter, _countryTranslations)
        _config.SaveKeyTextValue("countryTranslations", newStringWriter.ToString)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("CountryTranslations"))
    End Sub

End Class
```

`_config` is a misnamed helper class that stores and retrieves data from a local SqlCe instance.  Essentially the object is serialized, stored in the DB, and then pulled out of the DB any times it's needed and deserialized back into an object.  All in all, it seems to be working fairly well.

My problem is that although I can bind to the object, and I can monitor when a row is added in a WPF DataGrid via the CollectionChangedMethod handler, I don't get any notification when either of the two properties of CountryTranslation are changed.

The rest of my related code is... XAML... there's obviously more, but I don't believe the XAML portion of the binding is to blame, so I'll trim it to the relevant:

```xaml
<toolkit:DataGrid Margin="12,12,12,12" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=KarenSmith.CountryTranslations, Mode=TwoWay}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" SelectionMode="Single">
    <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Width="283" Binding="{Binding EnglishCountryName,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Width="283" Binding="{Binding ForeignCountryName,Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```

And the nice and simple code-behind:

```vb
Public Class Preferences

    Public Property KarenSmith As AmandaSeyfried = AmandaSeyfried.GetSingleton

    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        DataContext = Me

    End Sub

    Private Sub Close_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

If I throw some break points on the Getter and Setters of the CountryTranslation class, I can monitor when they're being changed (via the datagrid, so binding is working), but try as I might I can't figure out how to raise an event based upon that back in the main class to subsequently update the datastore to show the changes.

Comment: CollectionChanged occurs when the collection changes (not an item's property within the collection).  Update the datastore within the country name properties as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I add a `CollectionChanged` event to the `ObservableCollection`, which attaches a `PropertyChanged` event to it's items when they get added, and that event listener listens for changes and would handle them as needed.

Here's an example: (hope the syntax is correct since I just ran it through a C# to VB.Net converter)

```
Public Sub New()
    AddHandler MyCollection.CollectionChanged, AddressOf MyCollection_CollectionChanged
End Sub

Private Sub MyCollection_CollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As CollectionChangedEventArgs)
    If e.NewItems IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each item As MyItem In e.NewItems
            AddHandler item.PropertyChanged, AddressOf MyItem_PropertyChanged
        Next
    End If

    If e.OldItems IsNot Nothing Then
        For Each item As MyItem In e.OldItems
            RemoveHandler item.PropertyChanged, AddressOf MyItem_PropertyChanged
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub MyItem_PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
    If e.PropertyName = "Some Property" Then
        DoWork()
    End If
End Sub
```

The C# version looks like this:

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    MyCollection.CollectionChanged += MyCollection_CollectionChanged;
}

void MyCollection_CollectionChanged(object sender, CollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NewItems != null)
        foreach(MyItem item in e.NewItems)
            item.PropertyChanged += MyItem_PropertyChanged;

    if (e.OldItems != null)
        foreach(MyItem item in e.OldItems)
            item.PropertyChanged -= MyItem_PropertyChanged;
}

void MyItem_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Some Property")
        DoWork();
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  This put me on the right track of how to add an event handler to the items in the Observable Collection.  Awesome.